# Check if int variable is incremented by more than 4 since last check

Tags: python

I'm working on a project with a server and client using sockets to communicate.

I've been trying to find a solution to make a check to see if there has been no packages sent from the client to the server in the last 4 seconds.

```
package = clientsocket.recv(1024)  
    if package != "":
        time += 1
        message_empty = True
    else:
        time += 1
        message_empty = False

    #if message_empty is False and time has incremented by 4 since message_empty went from True to False then do something here
```

I want to do something like:

if message_empty is False and time has incremented by 4 since message_empty went from True to False then do something here.

From my Server I sent packages every second using Time.Sleep(1) so that is why I just increment by 1 for everything package as the packages are sent every second.

Comment: Have another variable which you set when you set `message_empty`, or instead of making `message_empty` a boolean, make it an int and use it for counting. There's no magic way of getting the "history" of a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it supposed to be simple and flag-free:

```
if package != "":
    time += 1
else:
    time = 0
if time >= 4:
    # Do something
```